# Do I need to create a reader and writer db instance when creating an AWS Aurora Serverless V2 cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm creating an AWS Aurora Serverless V2 Postgres database cluster (AWS::RDS::DBCluster) using Cloudformation and Serverless Framework (see below). It's unclear if I should also create two database instances (AWS::RDS::DBInstance) so that the cluster has a reader and writer instance available?

When I run through the AWS RDS Wizard the Aurora Serverless V2 cluster is automatically set up with two instances (reader and writer). I'm assuming I should do the same when creating the cloudformation script?

Cluster

```yaml
Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
DeletionPolicy: Delete
Properties:
  DBClusterIdentifier: db-test-cluster
  Engine: aurora-postgresql
  MasterUsername: username_from_secrets_manager
  MasterUserPassword: password_from_secrets_manager
  ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
    MinCapacity: 0.5
    MaxCapacity: 2
  BackupRetentionPeriod: 1
  DatabaseName: test-db
  EngineMode: provisioned
  Port: 5432
  Tags:
    - Key: "Name"
      Value: db-test-cluster
```

DbInstance 1 - reader

```yaml
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties:
  Engine: aurora-postgresql
  DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
  DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref auroraServerlessCluster
```

DbInstance 2 - writer

```yaml
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties:
  Engine: aurora-postgresql
  DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
  DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref auroraServerlessCluster
```

Do I need to specify these two db instances? When I don't specify these two instances my cluster is stick with "creating" as the status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no requirement to have any read-replica instances in an Aurora cluster (serverless or not). You can create an Aurora cluster with a single primary writer instance and nothing else. You can even create a cluster with no instances if you want, although that certainly has limited functionality.

Comment: If I don't have a read replica, I assume I'm not able to read any data from the cluster?

Comment: You can read from any instance. The "writer" is a read/write server. It just happens to be the only one that you can write to, so it's called the "writer".

Comment: @MarkB Do I have to (or should I) explicitly specify to which node to write data and from which to read from for better performance? Or Aurora Engine deals with read/write requests behind the scenes?

Comment: @GeorgeK you have to deal with that yourself. If Aurora dealt with that behind the scenes, then there wouldn't be a need for Aurora to provide you with separate endpoints.